# Simultaneous :hover for parent and its child element

Tags: jquery, hover, element, parent

is it possible to use jQuery to achieve a simultaneous ":hover" for both a parent AND a child element at the same time ? Specifically, i would like both the parent and the child to change background images when ever the cursor moves over the parent tag thus changing the child elements background as well.

The reason i ask is that i would like to make a nav-bar with out fixed with backgrounds so that its functions more dynamically when changing content. Please ask if any of this is unclear. Thanks you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to use jQuery to achieve this?

```
div.parent:hover {
background: red;
}

div.parent:hover div.child {
background: blue;
}
```

This won't work in IE6 since IE6 only supports :hover on A but the parent could be an A tag.

Comment: that's probably why he's asking for a jQuery solution ;-)

Comment: Well, it's not a problem to format your code to use anchors instead of divs to solve the problem. When IE9 is out, IE6 will probably be declared officially dead ;-)